# PHP access values in multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array called $ticket_quantities coming from an API which when I var dump comes out as

```
array(1) {
    [4128] => array(1) {
        [168] => array(2) {
            [7] => int(4)[8] => int(2)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the [7] => int(4) value and [8] => int(2) value?

Comment: php 101 `echo $ticket_quantities[4128][168][7]`

Comment: You will need recursion, so this could help: http://thisinterestsme.com/php-using-recursion-print-values-multidimensional-array/

Comment: How much variability is in this result data?  Are the keys known to you in advance?  Are the number of levels variable?  Do you always only want the "leaf nodes"?  The green tick is on a very weak answer.  Please improve your question by including more details.

Comment: These details clarify if you need a static set of nested loops, recursion, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$ticket_quantities[4128][168][7]
$ticket_quantities[4128][168][8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if You use `array_keys` function for undefined keys of incoming array. Look in this sample:

```
// rebuld Your array
$arr = array(4128 => array(168 => array(7 => 4,8 => 2)));
// get node of first level
$myArr = $arr[array_keys($arr)[0]];
// get node of second level
$myArr = $myArr[array_keys($myArr)[0]];

// get firs and second node from threed level
$One = $myArr[array_keys($myArr)[0]];
$Two = $myArr[array_keys($myArr)[1]];
print $One;
print '<hr>';
print $Two;
```